# Does distance between the shoulder joints vary with the movement of body in skeleton stream

Tags: kinect, distance, kinect-sdk, skeletal-animation

I want to measure the shoulder length of body using KINECT-2.0 but I don't know through which ratio it shows the output. If it changes which apparently seems so in the stream, then how can I measure it?

Comment: The fluctuation of data happens in my end too. You can try [JointSmoothing code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/045b058a-ae3a-4d01-beb6-b756631b4b42/joint-smoothing-code?forum=kinectv2sdk).